# How to skip Cucumber steps?

Tags: cucumber

I have the scenario like:

1. Given I go to this page
2. When I type cucumber
3. And I click
4. Then I should see the text
5. And I should not see the line

If I run this scenario it will execute all the 5 steps. But I want to skip the 4th step (Then I should see the text) and execute the 5th step.

Please give me your suggestions. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I agree with @Ernest's answer below; what you seem to be asking is a wrong use-case for Cucumber. Curious to know why you want this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) I need this functionality in my project. How can i proceed with these kind of scenarios? Give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TL;DR - don't do it - you're (probably) getting it wrong. And you can't (easily) do it. As Aslak wrote (one of Cucumber main creators):

> A step can have the following results:
>
> - undefined (no matching stepdef)
> - pending (a matching stepdef that throws PendingException)
> - passed (a matching stepdef that doesn't throw anything)
> - failed (a matching stepdef that throws an exception that isn't PendingException)
> - skipped (a step following a step that threw any exception (undefined, pending or failed))
>
> What you're asking for is a new kind of result - ignored. It could be
>   implemented by throwing an IgnoredException. This would mean that
>   skipped would have to be changed to: (a step following a step that
>   threw any exception (undefined, pending or failed) - unless the
>   exception was IgnoredException)
>
> I'm not sure I like this. It sounds like more complicated than it
>   needs to be. You already have the necessary information that something
>   is amiss - your step will either fail or be pending. I don't see the
>   value in continuing to execute the following steps. You still have to
>   implement the failing/pending step.
>
> As long as you're reminded that "there is work to be done here" I
>   don't think it's wortwhile complicating Cucumber to tell you what kind
>   of work needs to be done...
>
> Aslak

Whole discussion is here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cucumber/10146

Comment: I didn't know about 'pending', that is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I have had to skip steps conditionally based on environments. I used `next` to skip steps. Here is an example on how to do what you wanted.

```
Then /^I should see the text/$ do
    next if @environment == 'no text'

    ...
       <The actual step definition>
    ...
end
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? like Can we move to any step further by defining it in the "<the actual step definition>" part? and how do we define it?

Comment: 'next' skips everything below, it is kind of like 'return', which might work too. Program the steps like you usually would, but in the first line of the step, make an 'if' statement like the one above to not run the code below if you don't want to.

Comment: I dont get it, It throws an error to me when i type `next if` like `Invalid next (SyntaxError)`

Comment: I haven't used cucumber in a few years. If next has a new syntax let me know. Can you just call `next` on a step in general?