# Can I skip undefined steps in Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, gherkin

I have the same feature file that is used by frontend and backend testing, which have their own step definitions. For backend, I want to skip a few steps (e.g. frontend navigation).

I can either write empty step definitions, which will mark the steps as completed. I would rather if they were marked as "skipped" instead.

There is the problem though: If I have an undefined step, the test will fail. How can I configure Cucumber to skip the step instead and continue afterward?

I would prefer Javascript answers

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13988125/3092298

Answer (score 0):

I would define the step anyhow.

Your step definition would go something like this:

```
When("I go to the home page", notApplicable);
When("I go to page X", notApplicable);
When("I go to page Y", notApplicable);
When("I go to page Z", notApplicable);

function notApplicableStep() {
    console.log("Skipped. This step is not applicable.");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify :D This will however mark the steps as "done", not as "skipped", which is the whole point.

Comment: @MilanSmolík: Marking the steps "skipped" doesn't really benefit anything.